# Material-table with component as data not passing the component context in onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I tried to add component as data in material table but i'm not able to access 'this' context of the component to update state in the onChange function. The editable feature provided by the material-table does not fit my requirement.

```
class ClubList extends Component {
  state = { clubs: '', tableClubs: [] };

  changeDate=(change)=>{      
    console.log(this) //returns undefined.  I need to update state here but not able to access 'this' context of component
  }


  addClub = (event, clubs) => {
    let enteredClubs = this.state.clubs;
    let allClubs = this.props.clubs;
    let tableClubs = [];
    let enteredClubsArray = enteredClubs.split(/[ ,]+/);
    for (let clubs in enteredClubsArray) {
      tableClubs.push(allClubs.find(({ number }) => number == enteredClubsArray[clubs]));
    }
    tableClubs.map(
      (clubs) => (
        (clubs.scheduledDate = (        
          <DateComponent name="eventDate"
value={this.props.createData.eventDate} 
handleChange={this.changeDate} /> //Im calling the function here
        )),
        (clubs.city = clubs.city)
      )
    );
    this.setState({ clubs: '', tableClubs });
    this.clubsForCreate(tableClubs);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="clubSection">
            <TextComponent
              label="Enter Clubs"
              name="clubs"
              variant="outlined"
              handleChange={this.changeState}
              value={this.state.clubs}
            />
            <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={this.addClub} className="clubAddButton">

        <MaterialTable
          title="Clubs"
          columns={[
            { title: 'Date', field: 'scheduledDate' },
            { title: 'Status', field: 'statusDesc' },

          ]}
          data={this.state.tableClubs}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: heyy where are you using this changeDate function ???

Comment: Im calling it in the DateComponent inside addClub

Comment: check you are getting  console.log(this.state) inside changeDate or not and let me know.

Comment: Im getting undefined for 'this'. hence this.state throws me error

Comment: handleChange={(e) => this.changeDate()}  try to call function like this

Comment: tried that. It's just giving me the changed value but not the "this' context

Comment: how you are importion your Component  from react Vivek?

Comment: make your project online on codepen So i can help you easily Brother.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the function "changeDate" from arrow function to a normal function solved this issue. I guess the arrow function was removing the context of the callback function